# How to Show/Hide content of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have 8 product fill to UICollection View, but i just want show 4 product. When user click button "See more", interface will dropdown and show remain content. But i have no ideas about how to make this. My initial solution is i divided UICollectionView to 2 part, part one will show 4 product, part two will hidden and when i click button "see more" it will show them. But problem is : when part two hidden,postion of part two still here, i want position of button "see more" and all content below will content will be put up.

```
    if(collectionViewDM.hidden == true){
        collectionViewDM.hidden = false
    }
    else{
        collectionViewDM.hidden = true
    }      
}
```

Please help me, i'm beginner and i have no ideas about solution for problem

Comment: Why having tow collectionView buddy ?? Initially have 4 items in data source and show see more button on tapping it add 4 more item to the data source array and reload the collectionView it will now show 8 items isn't it

Comment: i set width and height of collectionView fit 4 items. so when i reload data for 8 items, interface not re-size.

Comment: so how can i resize collectionVien to fit 8 items?

Comment: Have a autolayout constraint on height of collectionView create an IBOutlet to it and update its constant buddy :) you anyway have method to calculate height to 4 cells call the same method now to calculate the hieght of 8 cells :)

Comment: i haved autolayout of collectionView turn on in storyboard, u have any code demo or solution for update height of collection view and below button auto adjust its position with size of UICollectionView

Comment: where is the ultimate solution?